# Are WordPress articles/blogs supposed to onebox in chat?

Tags: feature-request, support, chat

I could have sworn I've seen WP posts oneboxed in chat (or maybe not?)... but every time I post a WordPress URL it's not oneboxing.

Seeing that pasting `https://some-url` didn't work, I tried editing to `http://`.. [didn't work either](http://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/20752618#20752618).

Is it supposed to work? If so, what am I doing wrong? It not, ...can it be implemented?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I believe one-boxing occurs when it is [being posted by one of the chat feed bots](http://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/8595?m=20739829#20739829). But one-boxing when it is something you post yourself does not happen.

It is not the blog post itself that oneboxes, but the RSS-feed item posted by the chat feed bots.

Comment: Cool, I changed the feeds in the VBA chatroom, and it worked. I maintain the feature request then :)

Comment: You may want to post it on MSO @Mat'sMug.